# vue multiselect how to display tooltip or title on disabled options?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using vue multiselect to show list of currencies to users, when a currency isn't available for whatever reason i display that currency as disabled (using multiselect $isDisabled property)..the thing is i want to show a tooltip or title when hovering over this disabled option, but disabled options in vue multiselect have the "pointer-events: none" set on them using css and i can't do much about it as i can't manipulate the wrapper template of my custom options. what can i do to achieve what i want?

my code is as follows:

```
                  <multiselect
                      v-model="buyCurrency"
                      :options="canBuyCurrencies"
                      :show-labels="false"
                      :searchable="false"
                      :allow-empty="false"
                      :clear-on-select="false"
                      :close-on-select="true"
                      class="select-buy-currency"
                      @select="handleBuyCurrencyChange"
                  >
                    <template slot="option" slot-scope="props">
                      <div title="Test title" class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-apart align-items-center">
                        <img
                            class="option__image"
                            :src="`/img/flags/${props.option.code}.svg`"
                            :alt="props.option.code"
                        />
                        <div class="option__desc">
                        <span class="option__title">
                          {{ props.option.code }}
                        </span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </template>
                  </multiselect>
```

current code sets the title for all options, on hover the title shows for all options except the disabled ones.

EDIT: i tried going around this by enabling pointer events from css but that would make the disabled options clickable which causes an error that breaks the entire program, that's what i am getting

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'every')
    at VueComponent.wholeGroupSelected (vue-multiselect.min.js?8e5f:1:1)
    at VueComponent.selectGroup (vue-multiselect.min.js?8e5f:1:1)
    at mousedown (vue-multiselect.min.js?8e5f:1:1)
    at invokeWithErrorHandling (vue.common.dev.js?4650:1868:1)
    at HTMLSpanElement.invoker (vue.common.dev.js?4650:2193:1)
    at original._wrapper (vue.common.dev.js?4650:7587:1)
```

how can i override the default click behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on order of precedence, your component styling will usually always be able to override the CSS of a third party library. You just need to know what selector to use, which can be most easily figured out using your browser's DOM inspector.  A disabled option in vue-multiselect has classname `multiselect__option--disabled`, so you can apply this styling to fix your issue:

```css
<style scoped>
.select-buy-currency >>> .multiselect__option--disabled {
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
</style>
```

Note the use of the [deep selector](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors) which is needed in [scoped styles](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#mixing-local-and-global-styles) for targeting elements within child components (in this case, an option element inside `Multiselect` child component)

If you don't care about the style being scoped to a specific component and are ok with the style being applied globally you can leave off the `scoped` keyword and deep selector:

```css
<style>
.multiselect__option--disabled {
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
</style>
```

[codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-mirzakhani-2zwbgo?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: i know of this solution, this would allow the tooltips to show up on hover but will also make the option itself clickable/selectable, which causes errors. what i need is a way to show tooltips on hover and still prevent the option from responding to click events

Comment: it's not possible without changing the source code of vue-multiselect.  I'm not sure why disabled options are included in [this code](https://github.com/shentao/vue-multiselect/blob/master/src/Multiselect.vue#L132) attempting to select options by group.  Probably a bug.  It's possible you could fork vue-multiselect and modify it yourself.  Or you can catch the error and ignore it using [errorCaptured lifecycle hook](https://vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle.html#errorcaptured).  codesandbox updated showing how.

Comment: your solution works perfectly, and i learned something new about capturing errors in vue. thank you so much!